# Making Magento Admin Changes 'Future-proof'

Tags: admin, custom

Hi I am wanting to make some layout changes to the Magento admin panel including removing the Sales modules from the dashboard, example: http://puu.sh/kpUkL/3398735630.png

I would also like to make some internal changes to the way that users add products to the admin. For example I will be adding an automatic product specification system that will fill in some fields depending on the SKU that is entered.

I am confident on making these changes however I do question what might happen if I where to upgrade Magento in the future? Would I have to go back and make these changes all over again or can you code these changes for future updates?

Thanks

Comment: No if you don't directly edit the core files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are confident then go on. :-)

Basically if you do your work in the "right way", there will not be any problem in future upgrades. [Benmarks](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/5/benmarks) teaches the "right way" :

[image: did you edit the core ??]

ie **Do not edit the core**, instead use modular approach. Create a new module to extend the default functionality. If you follow this single rule, there is not going to happen any mistakes in future upgrades.